# Jumping on the Coordinate lattice grid

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, game-theory, integer-lattices, invariance

Mr. Fat moves around on the lattice points according to the following rules: From
point (x, y) he may move to any of the points $(y, x), (3x, −2y), (−2x, 3y), (x+1, y+4)$
and $(x − 1, y − 4).$ Show that if he starts at $(0, 1)$ he can never get to $(0, 0)$.

Comment: You are working with state machines. Find a variance.

Answer (score 3):

For a move from $(x,y)$ to one of the $(x', y')$, one has either $x'+y' \equiv x+y \pmod{5}$ or $x'+y' \equiv 3(x+y) \pmod{5}$. Initially it starts at $(0,1)$ with $0+1 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$, hence it can't reach $(0,0)$ with $0+0 \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$.

Comment: Nice solution ! I was thinking about invariance too but didn't thought of taking mod 5 :)